# parse json in flutter with riverpod an http

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

According to the flutter reference for  [parse JSON](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) I try to practice it. but unsuccessful.

```
class NameClass {
  final String name;
  NameClass({required this.name});
}
```

```
var nameList = [
  'Martine',
  'Els',
  'Dirk',
  'Alain',
];
```

### This is my class.

```
  final String gender;
  final int count;
  final String name;
  final double prob;
  const GenderData({
    required this.gender,
    required this.count,
    required this.name,
    required this.prob,
  });
  factory GenderData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return GenderData(
      gender: json['gender'] as String,
      count: json['count'] as int,
      name: json['name'] as String,
      prob: json['prob'] as double,
    );
  }
}
```

---

and this is Riverpod

```
  var _names = "name[]=" + nameList.join('&name[]=').toString();

  GenderData? out;
  Future<List<GenderData>> getGenderData() async {
    print("getGenderData out");
    final response =
        await get(Uri.parse('https://api.genderize.io/?${_names}'));
    print("response.body");
    print(response.body);
    return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
  }

  List<GenderData> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
    print("genderData out 1");
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    print("genderData out 2 parsed");
    print(parsed);
    out = parsed.map<GenderData>((json) => GenderData.fromJson(json)).toList();
    print("genderData out 3");
    return (out);
  }
```

The request returns successfully but during mapping it stops.
But it comes just print("genderData out 2 parsed")
What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();`

In this line, there isn't a need to cast the output of `jsonDecode()`; it is already a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Since your `genderData out 2 parsed` is the last thing getting printed, it indicates that something went wrong with your `fromJson()` function.

`fromJson()` functions can cause exceptions if the data type you defined mismatches with the one coming from API; That seems to be the issue in your case. You will have to catch those exceptions so that when this happens, your program fails gracefully.

Try adjusting the datatypes and using `try()`

Also, you don't need those `at` type casts in your data class definition.